# Where do I define the Content-Type I want to receive in my Django API?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django app that only needs to receive requests with Content-Type: text/plain.
Is there an option for that when using the GenericViewSet?

Comment: not sure if there is a parameter which tells what content-type should be accepted, but i would think about mixin which checks request.headers and searches for your expected content-type, if it is correct then pass or raise error if not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to write my own Parser for plain text (in my case, the body contains json although the Content-Type is plain text, so I just had to override media_type) like this:

```py
class PlainTextParser(JSONParser):
    media_type = "text/plain"
```

and use it in my ViewSet like this:

```py
parser_classes = [PlainTextParser]
```